# How convert soap web service to Rest in wso2 ESB

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I need to convert my existing SOAP web service to a REST webservice by using WSO2 ESB. I tried with the given samples in the Documentation successfully. And also I created a transformer proxy and set the end point as my existing WSDL url. In my case I'm getting the response as SOAP. SO how can I change that response into Json in the created proxy?   I tried with the outsequences a lot. but coudnt make it success. Can anyone tell me the exact steps to do this.
I riffered [enter link description here][1]

[1]: http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL as web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your REST API (see the example link given in Samisa's answer above) use the following property in out sequence to convert the message type to JSON.

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
```